# Blur a region shaped like a rounded rectangle inside an Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, image-editing

I want to blur a rectangle (with rounded corners) in an image using python pillow. I already found a way to blur only a certain part of a picture.

```
img = Image.open('assets/images/image.png')
x, y = 300, 1600

cropped_img = img.crop((x, y, 1000, 2600))

blurred_img = cropped_img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(20))

img.paste(blurred_img, (x, y))

img.save('assets/images/new.png')
img.show()
```

Furthermore I found a method to add rounded corners on a rectangle([Transparency issues drawing a rectangle with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48784578/transperancy-issues-drawing-a-rectangle-with-rounded-corners))

```
def round_corner(radius):
   corner = Image.new('RGBA', (radius, radius), (0, 0, 0, 0))
   draw = ImageDraw.Draw(corner)
   draw.pieslice((0, 0, radius * 2, radius * 2), 180, 270)
   return corner

def round_rectangle(rectangle, radius):
   corner = round_corner(radius)
   rectangle.paste(corner, (0, 0))
   rectangle.paste(corner.rotate(90), (0, rectangle.size[1] - radius))
   rectangle.paste(corner.rotate(180), (rectangle.size[0] - radius,   rectangle.size[1] - radius))
   rectangle.paste(corner.rotate(270), (rectangle.size[0] - radius, 0))
   return rectangle
```

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to combine these two source codes so that they work.

My Example Image:[image: example image]

Comment: Can you add your image `assets/images/image.png` to the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to do, is essentially to create a mask for the `Image.paste()` that only pastes those parts of the blurred image that lie inside the rounded rectangle.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
from PIL import ImageDraw

# when using an image as mask only the alpha channel is important
solid_fill =  (50,50,50,255) 


def create_rounded_rectangle_mask(rectangle, radius):
    # create mask image. all pixels set to translucent
    i = Image.new("RGBA",rectangle.size,(0,0,0,0))

    # create corner
    corner = Image.new('RGBA', (radius, radius), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(corner)
    # added the fill = .. you only drew a line, no fill
    draw.pieslice((0, 0, radius * 2, radius * 2), 180, 270, fill = solid_fill)

    # max_x, max_y
    mx,my = rectangle.size

    # paste corner rotated as needed
    # use corners alpha channel as mask

    i.paste(corner, (0, 0), corner)
    i.paste(corner.rotate(90), (0, my - radius),corner.rotate(90))
    i.paste(corner.rotate(180), (mx - radius,   my - radius),corner.rotate(180))
    i.paste(corner.rotate(270), (mx - radius, 0),corner.rotate(270))

    # draw both inner rects
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(i)
    draw.rectangle( [(radius,0),(mx-radius,my)],fill=solid_fill)
    draw.rectangle( [(0,radius),(mx,my-radius)],fill=solid_fill)

    return i
```

Mask:

[image: created mask]

Apply the mask to your image:

```
img = Image.open('pic.jpg')

x, y = 300, 160 
radius = 75

cropped_img = img.crop((x, y, 600, 600))

# the filter removes the alpha, you need to add it again by converting to RGBA
blurred_img = cropped_img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(20),).convert("RGBA")

# paste blurred, uses alphachannel of create_rounded_rectangle_mask() as mask 
# only those parts of the mask that have a non-zero alpha gets pasted
img.paste(blurred_img, (x, y), create_rounded_rectangle_mask(cropped_img,radius))

img.save('new2.png')
img.show()
```

---

I changed some dimensions and paths. Your code lacked the imports, I completed it to a [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

[image: Resulting Image, reduzed in size]

Comment: 0


I have attempted the code above. However, despite assigning a radius of 100 when the object is round, I am receiving the following error. Is there a way to apply a blurred effect in a circular shape? (The lines should have been green, but unfortunately they were not.) img : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUy1n.png

Comment: @Abdullah you need to create a mask that is circular and partly transparent and fully transparent every else where the circle does not apply. You seem to have a mix of circles and rectangles if I look a the picture. You can ask a new question, add your code, link to this question and hope that someone answers - I havent done PIL for some years now.