# How to blur part of a plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to blur a certain part of a plot in `ggplot`?

For example, consider the following plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

p <- 
  mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) 

p +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 100, xmax = 200, ymin = 15, ymax = 30,
           alpha = .1,fill = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

### Desired Output

I want to apply a blur effect in `p` over the area where there's currently a red rectangle.
A demonstration of what I'm looking for:

[image: demo with blur]

Is this even possible?

---

Reference: [Similar question (and answer) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433000/blur-a-region-shaped-like-a-rounded-rectangle-inside-an-image).

Comment: You might want to look into the [ggfx](https://ggfx.data-imaginist.com/) package

Comment: I'd plot data that needs blurring as a separate layer, then apply blur to that layer

Comment: @zx8754, I'm not sure I know how to translate your suggestion to code.

Comment: Testing it out myself at the moment, but the idea is we have 2 datasets, one normal geom_line(d1), 2nd dataset is wrapped into with_blur(geom_line(d2))

Comment: why don't you make your first attempt an answer for better visibility and also makes the question/answer thing a bit more clear. Also one can upvote this attempt as well. It deserves it.

Comment: taking it from your example, I'd probably generate a theme_void plot with your blurred patch and superimpose it onto the first plot with either cowplot or patchwork. But I really haven't even started to look into that wicked looking ggfx package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can split the data into two: data for normal plotting, data for blurring:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfx)

d1 <- mtcars
d1 <- d2 <- d1[ order(d1$disp), ]

ix1 <- range(which(d1$disp > 100 & d1$disp < 200)) + c(1, -1)
ix2 <- which(d1$disp < 100 | d1$disp > 200)

d1[ ix1[ 1 ]:ix1[ 2 ], "mpg" ] <- NA
d2[ ix2, "mpg" ] <- NA

ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = disp, y = mpg), d1) +
  with_blur(
    geom_line(aes(x = disp, y = mpg), d2),
    sigma = unit(1, 'mm')
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use ggfx' masks with a `geom_rect()` to determine a region of where to apply an effect. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(ggfx)

# Plot without line
p <- 
  mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) 

# Add mask as a reference
p + 
  as_reference(
    geom_rect(
      aes(xmin = 100, xmax = 200, ymin = 15, ymax = 30),
      inherit.aes = FALSE
    ),
    id = "draw_area" # <- set some name
  ) +
  # Plot blurry part with mask
  with_mask(
    with_blur(geom_line(), sigma = 5),
    mask = ch_alpha("draw_area")
  ) +
  # Plot crisp part with inverted mask
  with_mask(
    geom_line(),
    mask = ch_alpha("draw_area"),
    invert = TRUE
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

If you plan on using this a lot, you can make a wrapping function like so:

```
# trbl: Top, Right, Bottom, Left
area_effect <- function(layer, effect = with_blur, ..., trbl) {
  id <- rlang::hash(trbl)
  ref <- as_reference(
    annotate(
      "rect", xmin = trbl[4], xmax = trbl[2], ymin = trbl[3], ymax = trbl[1]
    ),
    id = id
  )
  mask1 <- with_mask(
    effect(layer, ...),
    mask = ch_alpha(id)
  )
  mask2 <- with_mask(
    layer, mask = ch_alpha(id), invert = TRUE
  )
  list(
    ref, mask1, mask2
  )
}

p +
  area_effect(geom_line(), trbl = c(30, 200, 15, 100), sigma = 5)
```

Comment: Since I do plan to use this a lot, I'm very excited with your `area_effect()`. However, trying this on a different plot leads to undesired graphical distortion. `p_mpg <- mpg %>% ggplot(aes(x = manufacturer, y = cty)) + geom_line() ; p_mpg_with_blur <- p_mpg + area_effect(geom_line(), trbl = c(20, 6, 10, 0.5), sigma = 5)`. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL1KL.png) that in `p_mpg_with_blur`, the lines outside the blurry area became strangely looking.

Comment: Actually, the same problem occurs also with your first method. So maybe it's an issue with `ggfx`?

Comment: Agreed, I think this might be an artefact of converting to rasters/pngs that happens under the hood. The lines are generally thicker. The lines on the right look like they might be weird due to overplotting and thereby stacking transparency values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my first attempt, using `{ggfx}` library, **but still not quite the desired output**.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(ggfx)

p_all_blurry <- 
  mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  with_blur(
    geom_line(),
    sigma = unit(1, 'mm')
  )+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) 

p_all_blurry
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

How could I limit the blurry area to where the red rectangle (in the question) is?